# C#, OpenXML, формула IF

Tags: c#, excel, if, openxml

Для создания файла Excel использую OpenXML. В файле Excel нужна формула IF(...). Создаю формулу при помощи кода:

```
new Cell = GetCell("D", 1, worksheetPart);
cell.CellFormula = new CellFormula("=IF(C1<35;10%;15%)");
cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);
```

где

```
private static Cell GetCell(string columnName, uint rowIndex, WorksheetPart worksheetPart)
        {
            Worksheet worksheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
            SheetData sheetData = worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
            string cellReference = columnName + rowIndex;

            // If the worksheet does not contain a row with the specified row index, insert one.
            Row row;
            if (sheetData.Elements<Row>().Where(r => r.RowIndex == rowIndex).Count() != 0)
            {
                row = sheetData.Elements<Row>().Where(r => r.RowIndex == rowIndex).First();
            }
            else
            {
                row = new Row() { RowIndex = rowIndex };
                sheetData.Append(row);
            }

            // If there is not a cell with the specified column name, insert one.  
            if (row.Elements<Cell>().Where(c => c.CellReference.Value == columnName + rowIndex).Count() > 0)
            {
                return row.Elements<Cell>().Where(c => c.CellReference.Value == cellReference).First();
            }
            else
            {
                // Cells must be in sequential order according to CellReference. Determine where to insert the new cell.
                Cell refCell = null; 
                foreach (Cell cell in row.Elements<Cell>())
                {
                    if (cell.CellReference.Value.Length == cellReference.Length)
                    {
                        if (string.Compare(cell.CellReference.Value, cellReference, true) > 0)
                        {
                            refCell = cell;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                Cell newCell = new Cell() { CellReference = cellReference };
                row.InsertBefore(newCell, refCell);

                worksheet.Save();
                return newCell;

            }
        }
```

Созданный файл Excel открывается с ошибкой, формула в целевых ячейках отсутствует. Без формулы IF все работает, в частности, формула sum работает прекрасно.

Comment: А открываешься ты в русском EXCEL или английском? Просто, в русском нужно писать ЕСЛИ вместо IF.

Comment: @iluxa1810, не может быть этого на уровне формата файла.

Comment: ЕСЛИ тоже не работает. Русский вариант формулы СУММ при первичной загрузке дает #ИМЯ?, SUM работает без вопросов.

Answer (score 1):

1. Строки надо заключать в кавычки: `@"=IF(C1<35;""10%"";""15%"")"`.
   Хотя лучше вообще числовую ячейку с процентным форматом использовать.
2. `;` или `,`?
3. `DataType` разве нужен?

Comment: Да, Вы правы - все дело было в запятых, т.е. рабочий вариант "=IF(C1<35,10%,15%)". Спасибо, вопрос исчерпан.

Comment: @АндрейЗорков, тогда прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.